# Puppeteer: check if click on button causes a navigation or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

In my script, I want to click on cookie consent dialogs, and depending on the website, some will just close the dialog, others will reload the entiere page.
How can I check if click on the button causes a navigation/reload or not?

Because if it's navigating, I have to call
`page.waitForNavigation(30000, { waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] })`
to make sure the site is fully loaded before taking a screenshot.

How can I archive this?

(Calling waitForNavigation without a navigation will result in a timeout)

Comment: In general, looking for logic that magically works on arbitrary websites is hard to write. I'd encourage reconsidering the extent you need to generalize. A couple options: Catch the `waitForNavigation` timeout and assume that the element closed or wait a fixed duration that would likely handle both types of situations. These are rather hacky solutions because they introduce a race condition, so I'd think waiting for a particular element on a page or otherwise adapting the navigation logic to a specific page and giving up on generalization is safest.

Comment: You can use [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) and check the status of the `page.waitForNavigation()` settled result.